# Excel - Providing a digest table based on items in another table, filtered by month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a number of worksheets that have tables in like so, which have a person name on the left, an appointment type across the top and the date of the appointments in the table.

[image]

I need to be able to produce a digest in another sheet, that shows all appointments that fall in the next month, that would look something along the lines of this:

[image]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Power Query to get the result directly:

1. Select Range and go to Data- From Table/Range- Open Power Query editor:
   [image]
2. Select all date Range and change format from DateTime to Date:
   [image]
3. Select all Date Range- go to Transform- select Unpivot columns:
   [image]
4. Filter Date and select Month: Next Month- Close and load:
   [image]

Comment: You're amazing Lee! I was playing around with Power Query as I use PowerBi but not Excel so much, but I was missing the pivot tables step.

Can I just ask, what app did you use to create the gifs? I could use that myself!

Cheers mate, perfect answer :)

Comment: @beebul, you can google LICEcap or download from this link directly: https://www.cockos.com/licecap/  :)

Comment: Great thanks :) 

I'm a big fan of their other software, Reaper for music production 